# I have a black tiny bug crawling all over the house

Tags: entomology, species-identification

This bug is crawling all around the house it stays within the shadows and moves very very slow, i have never seen it jump or run, it just moves very slowly

[image: DSC_108]

P.S. those bugs as u can see are smaller than 1mm so it's hard to take better pictures but i will get better ones tomorrow

P.S. the hairs are not hairs they are wool from the carpets, i just got married in october 2014 and everything in the house is new, including the flat, it was built in january 2014.

[Bug pictures with a 1 mm thick pencil refill](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/knxjw6psd793anb/AADuYjPZAmTRHmZjgKy4_Wdza?dl=0)

it is very similar to what's in this picture, but i couldn't take a picture of it because it's tooo tiny

I really need to know what it is so I can deal with it :(

Edit: once i found a very little few under the carpet but it generally stays away from the carpets and stays on the tiles and I don't think it is a termite because I don't find any piles of eaten wood

EDIT 2:
More pictures:

**-- Stage 1 --**

[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 1 of 2 Pic 1 of 4]
[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 1 of 2 Pic 2 of 4]
[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 1 of 2 Pic 3 of 4]
[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 1 of 2 Pic 4 of 4]

**-- Stage 2 --**

[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 2 of 2 Pic 1 of 2]
[image: Insect 1 of 2 Stage 2 of 2 Pic 2 of 2]

**[-- Video for stage 2 --](http://youtu.be/qR7s6LbbdOM)**

I don't know what it is but I know that there is ones young in age i call them stage 1 they are unable to move

and there are ones I call stage 2 older in age and bigger in size and they can move and I think they can bite too

**-- Insect 2 --** 5mm by 5mm

[image: Insect 2 of 2 Pic 1 of 2] [image: Insect 2 of 2 Pic 2 of 2]

I found this one across the hall from the others and I do't know if it's related, i found it dead but I haven't sprayed that side with insecticides i sprayed the other side so it's possible that it was with the others but ran and died far from them.

EDIT: More photos

P.S. I found those moving in daylight (now)

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

when i blew a little air i think i turned it

[image]

Comment: What region of the world are you located in?

Comment: The pictures are too blurry to make a certain species determination. To me, termites seems likely though. Can you see a clear waist? Do they have 6 legs?

Comment: @MattDMo I am from Egypt

Comment: Those photos dont provide enough detail--at least to me.

Comment: Added more photos the sources are at the dropbox folder cropped versions are in the question, PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I have added more photos please look at them, thanks

Comment: You write: "once i found a very little few under the carpet but it generally stays away from the carpets and stays on the tiles".
Could it be that they are simply less visible when in the carpet as when on the tiles ?

Comment: yes, it definitely could, if my tiles weren't whitish i would have never seen them, if they were on the carpets there is no way to see them

Comment: Can you keep some "stage 1" isolated in a jar with some dust and a tiny drop of water (just guessing what they might feed on) and see if they actually turn into "stage 2" ?

Comment: It seems from some of the photos that the "stage 2" have quite thin and long antennae, unlike what I've seen in termite images. Besides, the size is very small, so I wouldn't bet they are termites.

Comment: Let's hope it's not an insect that does irreversible damage like termites :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insect 1 is a:

> **Booklice**
>
> **Introduction**
>
> Booklice, also called psocids, are not true lice. While they resemble lice in size and shape, booklice feed only on fungi or mold. If you find them in grain or other stored food products, it is an indication of high humidity which encourages mold growth. In addition to food products, psocids may be found under wallpaper, in furniture, along the sides of windows or on window sills around potted plants. Booklice do not bite, transmit disease, or damage food or fabric, but they can be very annoying when present in large numbers.
>
> **Biology**
>
> [image: Booklice]
>
> Booklice found inside homes are wingless and very tiny: less than 1/16 of an inch long. While their back legs are thicker than the other four, and resemble the legs found in jumping insects, booklice do not jump, but run about rather quickly.
>
> Adult booklice range in color from translucent white to gray or brown. Females can produce about 60 eggs during the warm summer months and their life cycle (from egg to adult) can be completed in less than one month. When cool temperatures prevail, female booklice produce fewer eggs and the time required to complete their life cycle is over three months. Females deposit their eggs singly and often conceal them by covering with debris. Booklice undergo simple metamorphosis, that is their nymphs look just like adults except that they are much smaller and sexually immature. The common house-infesting booklice normally have four nymphal stages.
>
> **Injury**
>
> Booklice feed on molds and will overrun cereals and similar materials that support mold growth. Their presence, therefore, is a nuisance and can render some foods unfit. The starchy paste of wallpaper and books also can support mold growth or may be attacked directly by booklice. Outside of annoyance, their damage is insignificant.
>
> **Management**
>
> The best way to control booklice is to eliminate moist environmental conditions. Reducing the humidity in your home will eliminate the mold on which the booklice feed. Lowering the relative humidity to less than 50% will prevent their development. An air space under potted plants on windowsills will help keep the humidity down and reduce mold growth. Throw away any infested food material and make sure other foods are kept dry. Pesticides are not normally necessary to control booklice in homes.
>
> **Warning**
>
> Pesticides are poisonous. Read and follow directions and safety precautions on labels. Handle carefully and store in original labeled containers out of the reach of children, pets, and livestock. Dispose of empty containers right away, in a safe manner and place. Do not contaminate forage, streams, or ponds.

Source: [Penn State, Entomology: Booklice](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/booklice)

Comment: Nice find and great that you added an answer. Clearer pictures would have eliminated my termite guess at a much earlier stage.

Comment: Also, you should try to summarize information from sources, and not copy them directly. And if you do copy passages, you must show clearly that the text is a direct quote. I have reformatted your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** This is an *incorrect* answer. From the poster's [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31660/i-have-a-black-tiny-bug-crawling-all-over-the-house#comment53444_31790) above: "`Clearer pictures would have eliminated my termite guess at a much earlier stage`."

---

The organism you call 'stage 2' looks like a [termite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termite) to me, and the movement pattern shown in the video also fits well. They are mostly nocturnal, which also fits your observations. Your 'insect 2' is some sort of [Isopod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopoda) (an anthropod but not an insect), and unrelated to other organism. However, 1 mm is really small for a termite from what I know, but there are many different species and some can probably be that small. You should try to see if they have strait, beaded antennas and no narrow waist (which ants have) - both these characters are used to separate termites from ants.

Here is another [useful page on termites](https://insects.tamu.edu/extension/publications/epubs/e-368.cfm) from Texas A&M university, which includes more pictures and information on how to deal with infestations.

This picture shows soldiers (large jaws) and workers (pale heads) of the Formosan subterranean termite (*Coptotermes formosanus*).

[image]
(public domain picture from wikipedia)

Another possibility would be springtails (which are generally smaller than termites), but they are mostly found in moist soil, wood and similar environments, and they can jump.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about stage one, is it some sort of larva ?

Comment: Do the ones you call 'stage 1' move at all, or are they just dead? Termites naturally have eggs and nymph stages, but there shouldn't be any immobile stages outside of the nest. I still think the pictures are too blurry to really say, but termites (or ants) should be most likely. Can you see what their antenna looks like or if they have a narrow ant-waist (found in the suborder [Apocrita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrita))?

Comment: The small stage 1 they are immobile and they are not even standing on their legs because they have no resistance to air what so ever, they move when i blow slightly even if they blow while i am standing

Comment: I just had a call with my uncle he had a termite attack a few years ago, he asked me a question about any winged creatures, a month back we did have something that we thought are butterflies, I will mark you answer as correct simply because i think it's termites in very very very early stages and those stage 1 are yount termite nymphes

Comment: Insect 1 i not a termite, it's an insect that feeds on natural materials like cotton and wool ...etc, But the exterminator didn't now the english name

Comment: @ShereefMarzouk Do you mean insect 1 or stage 1 (or both)? Did he say what type of insect (moth, beetle etc)? Maybe a beetle from [Dermestidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae)? 1mm seems small for a Dermestidae beetle though.

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/31790/15476

Answer (score 3):

Insect #2 is not an insect, it seems to be a [woodlouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse) species. It's a small harmless detritivorous crustacean that likes dark and damp places. They are not uncommon in houses, but though they usually live outside. They probably died from waterloss after entering your house.