# Please Help Identify These Bugs

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I live in KwaZulu-Natal, South Africa, and the only indoor bugs I've experienced issues with are fleas, as I have two cats (and a big garden). This morning, however, I put on a fleece top that had been lying around somewhere, got a lift to the store, and returned to suddenly feel a crawling sensation. I lifted up my shirt to find these tiny bugs crawling all over my upper body. I did some Googling, went upstairs and carefully observed my bedding and bed, however, the only evidence I found was a few newborn fleas / flea larvae (which I intend to deal with today). I should also mention that a flock of wild Egyptian Geese have been raising five goslings in my yard, and they get very close to me when I'm walking outside at times. My house is also not carpeted, it has oregon pine floors throughout. I tried to take a photo of the critters, however, they're very tiny and move very quickly, so it was difficult to get a clear shot. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do they differ from the fleas you have?

Comment: They aren't fleas. The fleas look like fleas and jump around. These are very tiny, appear to look quite different to fleas, and crawl only. I did some Googling, and the closet thing I have found that looks similar is Book Lice.

Comment: Definitely look like book lice (psocoptera) to me. We already have a handful of quesions regarding these: see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/31660/16866), [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21864/16866), and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9638/16866)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a book louse (order Psocoptera). They feed on all kinds of organic matter, and are very common. Fun fact - they are called "book lice" because they are often associated with old books, feeding on the organic glues in the bindings. (they are also called bark lice - I'm sure you'd know why).